# Win32 File Properties dialog not displaying in Java Swing app via JNI

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface

I have a Java Swing application with a couple of pieces of native functionality added via JNI.  One thing this application does is show a tree view of the file system.  I was trying to write a little JNI so that, on Windows systems, I could provide a "Properties..." context menu item that displayed the standard file "Properties" dialog from Windows.

I scraped the internet for the Win32 code needed to do this, and came up with this:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_foobar_showFilePropertiesDialogImpl
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong hwnd, jstring fileName)
{
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlItem;
    HRESULT hr;
    IShellFolder *pFolder;
    IContextMenu *pContextMenu;
    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO cmi;
    const wchar_t *pszFile;

    if (!coInitialized)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Initializing COM (should happen just once)...", L"Initializing COM...", MB_OK);
#endif
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        coInitialized = true;
    }

    /* Get the name of the file. */
    pszFile = (wchar_t *)env->GetStringChars(fileName, NULL);
    if (pszFile==NULL) { /* Exception occurred */
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        env->ReleaseStringChars(fileName, (const jchar *)pszFile);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    hr = pFolder->ParseDisplayName(HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, (LPTSTR)pszFile, NULL, &pidl, NULL);
    pFolder->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        env->ReleaseStringChars(fileName, (const jchar *)pszFile);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void **)&pFolder, &pidlItem);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        SHFree(pidl);
        env->ReleaseStringChars(fileName, (const jchar *)pszFile);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    hr = pFolder->GetUIObjectOf(HWND_DESKTOP, 1, (LPCITEMIDLIST *)&pidlItem, IID_IContextMenu, NULL, (void **)&pContextMenu);
    pFolder->Release();
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ZeroMemory(&cmi, sizeof(cmi));
        cmi.cbSize = sizeof(cmi);
        if (hwnd>0)
        {
            cmi.hwnd = (HWND)hwnd;
        }
        cmi.lpVerb = "properties";
        cmi.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
        hr = pContextMenu->InvokeCommand(&cmi);
#ifdef DEBUG
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            wchar_t msg[2048];
            wsprintf(msg, L"InvokeCommand failed: %d - %x", SUCCEEDED(hr), hr);
            MessageBoxW(NULL, pszFile, msg, MB_OK);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"InvokeCommand successful!", L"InvokeCommand Status", MB_OK);
        }
#endif
    }

    pContextMenu->Release();
    SHFree(pidl);
    env->ReleaseStringChars(fileName, (const jchar *)pszFile);

    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

From Java, I run this method from the EDT.  Unfortunately, the properties dialog doesn't display *if* DEBUG is not defined.  It seems that if I define DEBUG, the properties dialog will pop up after the "InvokeCommand successful!" MessageBox.

Another thing I noticed is, when DEBUG is not defined, I call this method (and the properties dialog is not displayed), it *will* display later on in the application if I open a different "native" window.  For example, I have code that opens the native Delete dialog via SHFileOperation (which works); as soon as I display that dialog, any File properties dialogs that didn't originally display will suddenly appear.

It seems as though I'm doing stuff on the wrong thread perhaps.  Is the EDT not the thread I want to display native windows from?  But I'm confused because again, the delete dialog is working fine.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the windows event queue.  This is *not* something you want to do on the event dispatch thread (that's for Swing/AWT consistency, which doesn't encompass unrelated native windows like the properties box).

Comment: `MessageBox()` runs its own message loop, which is probably not interacting correctly with Swing's message processing. Try not to invoke native methods that invoke their own message processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of digging through the Shell interfaces manually, try using `ShellExecute()` instead and let the OS do the heavy work for you:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_foobar_showFilePropertiesDialogImpl 
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong hwnd, jstring fileName) 
{ 
    /* Get the name of the file. */ 
    const wchar_t *pszFile = (wchar_t *)env->GetStringChars(fileName, NULL); 
    if (pszFile==NULL) { /* Exception occurred */ 
        return JNI_FALSE; 
    } 

    int iErr = (int) ShellExecuteW((HWND)hwnd, L"properties", pszFile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    env->ReleaseStringChars(fileName, (const jchar *)pszFile); 

    /*
    wchar_t msg[36];
    if (iErr > 32)
        wsprintfW(msg, L"ShellExecute successful!"); 
    else 
        wsprintfW(msg, L"ShellExecute failed: %d", iErr); 
    MessageBoxW((HWND)hwnd, pszFile, msg, MB_OK); 
    */

    return JNI_TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I ended up having to use ShellExecuteEx instead of ShellExecute though, since the former let me set the magic SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST flag, which was the last piece of the puzzle for invoking shortcut menu verbs.  Thanks!